# Science fiction novel with one-armed protagonist and a homicidal squirrel

Tags: story-identification, novel

When I was a kid, I remember reading a science fiction novel in which the main character loses an arm at some point, and has a run in with a homicidal squirrel.  Does anyone know what this was?

For what it's worth, I remember it was one of four novels published in a single volume collection, one of the other's was Alfred Bester's "The Demolished Man".

Comment: One arm makes me think of [Gil Hamilton][https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gil_Hamilton], but no squirrel.

Comment: For four-works collections, ISFDb lists [this one](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?15928) though I don't know of a killer squirrel in those works. There's also [this one](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?565328), in French, though.

Comment: "Homicidal squirrel" makes me think of Mudge (the otter) from Spellsinger.

Comment: Thanks for the link to isfdb!  It turns out I misremembered - the novel wasn't in that collection after all...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Necromancer by Gordon R Dickson - chronologically it is the first in his Childe Cycle of novels

The main protagonist Paul Formaine loses an arm in a mining accident.

At a later point in the story he is undergoing initiation into the Chantry Guild during which he has to fight off an unexpected attack, which takes the form of a telepathically controlled squirrel trying to shoot him with his own gun while he is resting in a forest.

Comment: Looking on [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3732) I can't see an anthology where this story and Alfred Bester's "The Demolished Man" are collected together so the OP may be mistaken about that.

Comment: Great - thanks a lot!  That is exactly the one, the arm was lost in a mining accident...